# Calculating the age of two LocalDates

Tags: java, android

Code:

```
 public String Calcage(){
    int age = 0;
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

        Date birth = sdf.parse(dateOfBirth);
        Date d = new Date();

        LocalDate birthday = birth.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        LocalDate now = d.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

         age = Period.between(birthday, now).getYears();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return String.valueOf(age);
}
```

**PROBLEM:** It returns zero every time. The Date which I use for testing is 1985-01-07

Comment: Why do you mix up the old and the new api? I'm not an Android dude but when you have access to `java.time`, can't you just use it for everything?

Comment: You should include in the question how dateOfBirth is defined

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually using 1985-01-07 it correctly returns 0 and should also throw a ParseException which will be caught from the catch block and the stacktrace will be printed.
Your code should work for 07.01.1985 and return 35.
if you want nevertheless to use 1985-01-07 you should edit the specified format to "yyyy-dd-MM" or "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: this actually works, but I have to work with the date 1985-01-07. Or is there a way to parse it ot 07.01.1985

Comment: just change SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"); to
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM"); if 01 is the day and 07 is the month, or to yyyy-MM-dd if it's the opposite